# How to include an XML Layout into an Android library

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

Basically I am trying to make an Android library which needs to have an XML Layout.

But the problem I am facing is that I cannot see an Layout Folder under my res folder.

Till now I have figured out that a custom view can be made and used using a Java Class, but I am not in an favour of using this method as I am not very knowledgeable in making layouts using java.

My research till now has given me an Idea that Is it possible for my Library class to accept an layout and the ids of views inside the layout and then use them as needed.

OR

Is there any other way of doing it?

Any Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the problem I am facing is that I cannot see an Layout Folder under my res folder.

You are welcome to create a `res/layout/` directory yourself. There are an infinite number of resource directories; few will be created for you when you create your project.

You can use the file manager that is part of your desktop OS to create this directory. Or, from Android Studio, you can right-click over the `res/` directory, choose New > Directory from the context menu, and enter `layout` for the name.

Comment: Extremely Thank You for the Answer. But the `R.id.viewid` is showing error. Can You please help to solve this.

Comment: @RajeshK: I suggestt that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve]. That would include the layout resource, the code referencing `R.id.viewid`, and what the error is.

Comment: Sorry and Thanks as the issue was solved after adding the layout file. Thanks once again.